# Selectively change the scale of one out of "X" number of graphs using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, scaling, linegraph

I have nine graphs in total, and the scaling on one of them makes the data visualisation for the other a bit of a pain, as shown in the image below:

[image: Linegraphs]

For reference: X = date, Y = crime occurrencies, Color = crime type

All the other 6 graphs look similar to the first two. Only London has such a high amount of Anti-social Behavior crime occurrencies that kind of ruins the party.

My ideal output would be a different scaling for London, shown on the right side of the Y axis possibly?

My knowledge of ggplot is limited though, so feel free to share any more efficient data visualisation tips.

Here's the code I'm using to plot the graphs:

```
crimedata %>% count(Region, Month, Crime, name = 'Crime_occurrencies') %>%
mutate(Date = as.Date(paste0(Month, '-01'))) %>%
ggplot() + aes(Date, Crime_occurrencies, col = Crime) + 
geom_line() + 
facet_wrap(~Region) + #create a line graph for each region
scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-10-01"), by="1 month"),
           date_labels = '%m %Y') +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle =- 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

And here's a randomised sample of the data frame:

```
structure(list(Month = c("2020-06", "2019-02", "2019-12", "2019-11", 
  "2019-04", "2020-04", "2020-07", "2020-01", "2019-05", "2019-12"),  
Region = c("London", 
  "London", "South East", "Yorkshire and The Humber", "South East", 
  "West Midlands", "Yorkshire and The Humber", "Yorkshire and The Humber", 
  "London", "North West"), 
Crime = c("Anti-social behaviour", "Violence and sexual offences", 
  "Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", 
  "Anti-social behaviour", "Robbery", "Violence and sexual offences", 
  "Anti-social behaviour", "Robbery")), 
row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001cfda8e1ef0>)
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: How about using `facet_wrap(..., scales = "free_y")`?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot, if you submit this as your answer I'll accept it :)